# Inequality $\sum\left ( \frac{a}{2a+b} \right )^3\geqslant \frac{1}{9}.$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers. Prove that
$$\left ( \frac{a}{2a+b} \right )^3+\left ( \frac{b}{2b+c} \right )^3+\left ( \frac{c}{2c+a} \right )^3\geqslant \frac{1}{9}.$$
P/S: I have used many ways but all are wrong.

Comment: You refer to variable `c` but I don't see it in the inequality.

Comment: The sum is intended to be "cyclic," i.e., the second term has $b, c$ and the third $c, a.$

Comment: Can you prove the square version, namely $ \sum (\frac{a}{2a+b})^2 \geq 1/3$?

Comment: @CalvinLin Yeahh, this is proved quite simply using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. But in case of exponent 3 this is wrong!

Comment: Can't you power mean it to the square version then CS it?

Comment: @CalvinLin I proved based on the technique mentioned on page 241, but it seems very complicated. Link: https://www.isinj.com/mt-usamo/Secrets%20in%20Inequalities%20(volume%201)%20Pham%20Kim%20Hung.pdf

Comment: Ah, I misspoke. I was doing $ \sum (\frac{a}{a+2b} ) ^2 \geq 1/3$ instead. It's less clear to me how to proceed with this.

Comment: @Barron You need to add more details of your attempt.

Comment: @CalvinLin Is inequality $\sum_{\text{cyc}} (\frac{a}{2a+b} ) ^2 \geqslant 1/3$ true? I came up with a way to convert the original inequality to a proof of this inequality.

Answer (score 1):

You let $\dfrac{b}{a} = x\dots $ etc and get $g(x,y,z) = xyz = 1, x,y,z > 0$ and:
$$f(x,y,z) = \sum_{\text{cyc}}\dfrac{1}{(2+x)^3}\geq \dfrac{1}{9}.$$

This is one of those rare times where Lagrange multiplier can actually help because the equation $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$ results in:
$$\dfrac{(x+2)^4}{x} = \dfrac{(y+2)^4}{y} = \dfrac{(z+2)^4}{z}$$
and it forces at least two of them equal to be equal. This is because you can see that function $\dfrac{(t+2)^4}{t}$ is convex on $t > 0$ with only one local minimum. So you find all "interior" critical points like that and none of the local minima you find that is smaller than $\dfrac{1}{9}.$

For the behavior on the boundary, if $x$ is really small for example, then $f(x,y,z) > \dfrac{1}{(2+x)^3} > \dfrac{1}{9}.$ So you can get a closed domain with $x,y,z\in[m, M]$ and then look at $f(x,y,z)$ on the boundary and find the minimum there.

Obviously, this is just the outline and some details are left out.